# Display the dropdown selected value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a simple markup of twitter bootstrap dropdown menu where I need to display the selected value but its not happening.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 10em;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Select                         <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">APP1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">APP2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">APP3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
            //Need to show the selected Value
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the above code click event is working but value is not getting selected and displayed.
How to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).text()` to get selected value text:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
      console.log($(this).text());
      var cache = $('.btn-primary').children();
      $('.btn-primary').text($(this).text()).append(cache);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 10em;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Select                         <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">APP1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">APP2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">APP3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.How to display the selected value at `Select` ..I mean I need to display the selected value in dropdown

Comment: @Lara   display the selected value at Select means?? not getting you...

Comment: I meant whatever value is selected in the dropdown, that should display as default until another value is not selected

Comment: i cant find any selectbox in yout html...There is only "Select" inside button

Comment: Yes, the same `Select` I want to be replaced with Selected Value from dropdown

Comment: Its working. Only one thing I wanted to ask more is , Why dropdown icon is disappearing on selecting of value ? How to get keep it as it was before , so that it will look like dropdown ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead to use [jQuery click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) you can use directly the bootstrap "click.bs.dropdown" event.

My snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  
  $('.dropdown').on('click.bs.dropdown', 'a', function (e) {
    $('.dropdown .btn:first-child')[0].childNodes[0].textContent = e.target.textContent + ' ';
  });

  // In order to start with an element selected you can:
  $('.dropdown').find('a:contains("APP3")').trigger('click.bs.dropdown');
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="padding-top: 10em;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Select                         <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">APP1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">APP2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">APP3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```